# RecyclerView : One OnClickListener over various items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I'm using a RecyclerView with 2 holder types (Title and Item) to display the activity's content. The quantity of Items per Title is undefined.
Just like this :

```
Title
-Item
-Item

Title
-Item

Title
-Item
-Item
-Item
```

I'm looking for a clue. How can I set an OnClickListener on each group (Title + Items), so that the "OnClick gray wave effect" browse the entire selected group without interruption?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that to achieve this you will need to put the whole group inside a single row (Title + n Items) and handle the views programatically. You can give the parent layout `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` to achieve the ripple effect when clicked (Be sure to give it an `onClickListener` or at least set `android:clickable="true"`).

What you can do is, inside each Title view, you can add your items in a `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView` and disable its scrolling using `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`, so it will give you the same result.

Comment: Yes, but doing this it won't recycle the views anymore. :(

Comment: True. The whole group view will be recycled but each item under the title won't. You can use this if you don't have many items in each group.

Comment: I have a lot of complexes views... :( Btw, Thank you for your help ;)

Answer (score -1):

if you want OnClickListener in each items or put them in Linearlayout and give it id  you need to create interface and implement it in the screen you want to show the recycleview adapter  and use it in adapter

```
public interface OnLevelClick {

void onTitleClick(int pos);
void onItem(int pos);
}
    OnLevelClick onLevelClick;
    public LevelAdapters(Activity activity, ArrayList<Items>   
    arrayListItems, OnLevelClick onLevelClick) {
    this.arrayListItems = arrayListItems;
    this.onLevelClick = onLevelClick;
    this.activity =activity;

}

     @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int 
   position) {
      holder.tvTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
           onLevelClick.onTitleClick(position);

           }
          ////   or
              holder.linear.setOnClickListener(new 
             View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
           onLevelClick.onTitleClick(position);

           }
```

in the activity implement

```
       Activity implements OnLevelClick{
    levelAdapter = new        
     LevelAdapters(getActivity(),savedLevelList,this);
    reLevel.setAdapter(levelAdapter);
          @Override
    public void onNumClick(int pos) {


     Log.d("Title",arraylist.get(po0s).getTitle());

    }
```

}